# populating pandas columns based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe contains these columns

```
ID   Address1   Address1-State   Address1-City  Address2  Address2-State  Address2-City   Address    State      City
 1    6th street   MN              Mpls
 2                                               15th St      MI           Flint
 3                 MA              Boston          Essex St   NY            New York
 4    7 street SE  MN              Mpls           8th St      IL             Chicago
```

Now I want to populate Address field in such a way that if Address1 is blank,populate Address2 and the state city fields of Address2

In the above case final dataframe would be like this

```
 ID     Address   State    City
  1      6th street   MN    Mpls
  2      15th St      MI    Flint
  3      Essex St     NY     New York
  4     7 street SE  MN     Mpls
```

Currently,I am doing this

```
def fill_add(address1,address2):
if address1!='':
    address=address1

elif address1=='' and address2!='':
    address=address2
elif address1=='' and address2=='':
     address=''

return address


def fill_add_apply(df):
df['Address']=df.apply(lambda row:fill_add(row['Address1'],row['Address2']),axis=1)
```

Do I have to do the same for all the other columns?Is there a better way?

Just to clarify, in ID=3 Address,State,City should be "Essex St NY New York" because Address 1 is blank so it should choose Address2 and the city and state of Address2.
In short, if Address1 is blank it should choose Address2,Address2-State and  Address2-City,even if Address1-State and  Address1-City are not blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st modify your column , then using `groupby` +`first`

```
df=df.replace('',np.nan)#prepare for first 

df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('\d+','')
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('-').str[-1]
newdf=df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).first()
newdf.loc[df.iloc[:,1].isnull(),:]=df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).last()
newdf
Out[40]: 
       Address      City  ID State
0  6th street       Mpls   1    MN
1      15th St     Flint   2    MI
2    Essexb St  New York   3    NY
3  7 street SE      Mpls   4    MN
```

Comment: Thanks! But in ID=3 it should be "Essex St   NY            New York" because Address 1 is blank so it should choose Address2 and the city and state of Address2.

Comment: @amandasmith check the update, also if this is what you need , would you like accept it ?  check mark at the left

Answer (score 0):

(Given you do not have any duplicate index)

Select indices you want to fill with Adress1:

```
Address1_index = df.loc[!df.Address1.empty() and !df.Address1-State.empty() and !df.Address1-City.empty()].index
```

then put Address1 data in your desired columns:

```
df.loc[Adress1_index, ["Adress", "State", "City"]] = df.loc[Adress1_index, ["Adress1", "Adress1-State", "Adress1-City"]]
```

Now select indices you want to fill with address2:

```
Address2_index = df.loc[df.Adress1.empty() or df.Adress1-State.empty() or df.Adress1-City.empty()].index
```

then fill these also:

```
df.loc[Adress2_index, ["Adress", "State", "City"]] = df.loc[Adress2_index, ["Adress2", "Adress2-State", "Adress2-City"]]
```

Remove columns that you do not want:

```
df.drop(["Address1", "Adress1-State", "Adress1-City", "Address2", "Adress2-State", "Adress2-City"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

df=df.replace('',np.nan)

addr_1=['ID','Address1','Address1-State','Address1-City']
addr_2=['ID','Address2','Address2-State','Address2-City']

new_df=pd.DataFrame(df[addr_1].values.copy(),columns=['ID','Address','State','City'])

new_df.loc[new_df['Address'].isnull(),:]=df.loc[df['Address1'].isnull(),addr_2].values

#print(new_df)
    ID  Address     State   City
0   1   6th street  MN      Mpls
1   2   15th St     MI      Flint
2   3   Essex St    NY      New York
3   4   7 street SE MN      Mpls
```